# Не могу сделать <canvas> фоном сайта

Tags: css, html5, html5-canvas

Не могу объединить картинку, надпись **Hello my friend** и анимацию `<canvas>`. Получается либо так, что `canvas` вытесняет `logo` и `titles`, либо `<canvas>` просто закрывает `logo и titles`.

Помогите пожалуйста.Заранее спасибо.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ALIAS1/zwn5e0xy/),

```css
.wtars {
  z-index: 1;
}

#stars {
  position: relative;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  477ab9 width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#stars:hover {
  background: #3D689C;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 680px;
}

.container {
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ot {}

.logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.titles {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wtars">
    <canvas id="stars"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ot">
      <img src="img/logo3.jpg" alt="chel" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <h1>my friend</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<script src="http://atuin.ru/js/art/stars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: В идеале надо бы убирать из кода всё лишнее, что не влияет на саму задачу... Так людям легче будет найти, где косяк...

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает.

```css
.wtars {
  position: relative;
}

#stars {
  position: absolute;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  477ab9 width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#stars:hover {
  background: #3D689C;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 680px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ot {}

.logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.titles {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wtars">
    <canvas id="stars"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ot">
      <img src="img/logo3.jpg" alt="chel" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <h1>my friend</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<script src="http://atuin.ru/js/art/stars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `canvas.toDataURL()`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("stars");
// Draw on canvas here
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + canvas.toDataURL() + "\"";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<canvas id="stars" style="display: none;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```